# SQL update field in the table only if the field is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateContractInfo](@UserGroupId int, @Quantity int, @ContractName varchar(150))
AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE [contract]
    SET totalUsers = @Quantity, contractName = @ContractName
    WHERE userGroupId = @UserGroupId
END
```

I want to enhance that query a bit to check first the contractName column. 
If the column is null then proceed with update of contractName otherwise skip the update of that field.

totalUsers field should be updated one way or another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [`CASE STATEMENT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

Try This

```
UPDATE [contract]
SET totalUsers = @Quantity, 
contractName = CASE WHEN contractName IS NULL THEN @ContractName ELSE contractName END
WHERE userGroupId = @UserGroupId
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you can try to is [`ISNULL()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) function

```
UPDATE [contract]
SET totalUsers = @Quantity, 
contractName = ISNULL(contractName, @contractName)
WHERE userGroupId = @UserGroupId
```

Comment: should the ISNULL parameters be switched?